# Entity Framework and (1 to many)-(many to 1) (1 - * * - 1) relations

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4

Iam have some trouble for some time to figure out how to take data from a data table (MSSQL 2008). Problem is this. You have 3 tables:

- TABLE1 (Jobs): JobID, JobName
- TABLE2 (Worker): WorkerID, WorkerName
- TABLE3 (Worker2Job): RowID, WorkerID, JobID

I Assume that JOB can be done by many workers, so I need "Worker2Job" table. So I can type that JobID:1 is made by WorkerID1 and WorkerId2 etc...

Now using Entity framework I dont know how to fetch the "WorkerName" property for the first of worker (nor any other list of workers).

Any ideas ?! 
Thx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any special `RowId` in `Worker2Job`. Just define your `Worker2Job` with only two columns: `WorkerId` and `JobId` and make both these columns composite primary key of the table. Once you add all three tables to the entity designer it will automatically see many-to-many relation and create only two entities with the correct relation in the model. `Worker` entity will have `Jobs` navigation property and `Job` will have `Workers` navigation property. You will be able to write query like:

```
var query = context.Jobs.Include("Worker").Where(j => j.JobId == someId);
```

Such query will load a job with all related workers and you will have access to their names.

Comment: Thx! I didn't know that. I would need to digest some book about EntityFramework because I think I miss many features. Anyway I will try your solution (which probably is working good). In the mean time I also have come up with a solution. I just used the: worker = (from c in worker2job where c.jobid = jobid select c.worker) ... and to my amusement it works fine... I will try your solution for performance checks. Thx!