# has-relation in linq-statement?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4

I have three tables. Question, Discipline and QuestionHasDiscipline. QuestionHasDiscipline holds the relation between Question and Discipline. They all have an unique id-column to identify them.

I am trying to write a linq-statement that returns all the questions that have a certain discipline.

What I have begun doing is this:

```
               var questions = (from q in context.Questions
                             where (from d in context.QuestionHasDiscipline
                                    where d.QuestionId == q.QuestionId
                                    ) ...
```

But it obviously is horribly wrong. I've tried different approaches but now I turn to the greater minds.. Any suggestions?

Comment: Looks very similar to another question I answered today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322145/entity-framework-and-1-to-many-many-to-1-1-1-relations/6322197#6322197

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.Any()` with a predicate.

```
from q in context.Questions
where context.QuestionHasDiscipline.Any(d => d.QuestionId == q.QuestionId)
select q;
```

Comment: Just gotta say, I keep coming back to this one and it saves me everytime. Thanks again!